# networkx : Plot a graph with common attributes

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to create a graph with nodes and edges. The data I had was divided into Members and topics taken by them. Now I processed the data in this form where for each topic i have found the members who take that topic:

```
T498    ['M1', 'M3', 'M5', 'M7', 'M16', 'M20']                  
T611    ['M2', 'M3', 'M4', 'M6', 'M7', 'M8', 'M9', 'M10', 'M11', 'M12', 'M13', 'M14', 'M15', 'M17', 'M18', 'M19']
```

How can I join these member nodes to that topic?
Also if i have responses for each member like "Yes", "No" , how can i use them as weights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nodes and edges are like dictionaries which can hold any sort of information you want. For example, you can label each node whether it's a topic or member and when it's time to plot, you can define its label, size, color, font size, etc based on that information.

Here is a basic example where you change the color of each edge based on the member's response, instead of its thickness or some other attribute.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

topics = {
    'T498': [('M1', 0), ('M3', 1), ('M5', 1), ('M7', 0), ('M8', 0)],
    'T611': [('M2', 1), ('M3', 1), ('M4', 0), ('M6', 1), ('M7', 0)],
}

G = nx.Graph()
for topic, members in topics.items():
    # You just need `G.add_node(node)`, everything else after that is an attribute
    G.add_node(topic, type='topic')
    for member, response in members:
        if member not in G.nodes:
            G.add_node(member, type='member')
        # `G.add_edge(node1, node2)`, the rest are attributes
        G.add_edge(topic, member, response=response)

node_sizes = [1000 if attrs['type'] == 'topic' else 500 for attrs in G.nodes.values()]
node_colors = ['r' if attrs['type'] == 'topic' else '#1f78b4' for attrs in G.nodes.values()]
edge_colors = ['y' if attrs['response'] else 'k' for attrs in G.edges.values()]
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)
nx.draw(G, pos, node_size=node_sizes, node_color=node_colors, edge_color=edge_colors)
plt.show()
```

Output

[image: 1]